# printf() not printing in pthread after a call to sleep()

Tags: c, linux, printf, xilinx, petalinux

sleep() for more than 2 seconds in my c project on my zedboard running petalinux is misbehaving. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    printf("Main sleep\n");
    sleep(3);
    printf("Main wakeup\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    exit(0);
}
```

Sleep for 3 seconds and I do not see the wakeup print statement, nor does the program exit. I have to hit enter once or twice and then the program exits without printing wakeup. If I sleep for 2 seconds then the program behaves as expected.

Only reproducible on zedboard running petalinux. Same code compiled and running on my laptop does not have this strange behavior

I am connected to the zedboard via serial console. The serial device that the console is running on in the zedboard is the default /dev/ttyPS0

Edit: Changed the question, has nothing to do with multithreading. Added the most simple reproducible example

Edit:
I added the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tme = *localtime(&t);
    printf("Main sleep at %d seconds\n", tme.tm_sec);
    sleep(3);
    t = time(NULL);
    tme = *localtime(&t);
    printf("Main wakeup at %d seconds\n", tme.tm_sec);
    fflush(stdout);
    exit(0);
}
```

I ran the program as so:

```
root@zed:~# ./payload-software > a.txt
```

The program did not exit until I hit enter, I waited 20 seconds. I cat the file and here is the result:

```
root@zed:~# cat a.txt 
Main sleep at 35 seconds
Main wakeup at 38 seconds
```

Program is sleeping like it should but it is not exiting and it is not printing to stdout when I run it without file redirect. If i change sleep time to 2 seconds it works fine.

Edit: Add strace:

```
root@zed:~# strace payload-software
execve("/usr/bin/payload-software", ["payload-software"], 0xbe9f8dd0 /* 13 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x4dd000
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="zed", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6146, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 6146, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f98000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0@\33\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=22176, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f96000
mmap2(NULL, 86248, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f5a000
mprotect(0xb6f5f000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6f6e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0xb6f6e000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0]V\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=75704, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 147656, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f35000
mprotect(0xb6f47000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6f56000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x11000) = 0xb6f56000
mmap2(0xb6f58000, 4296, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f58000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbeab1178) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/v7l/neon/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l/neon", 0xbeab1178) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/v7l/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l/vfp", 0xbeab1178)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/v7l/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l", 0xbeab1178)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/neon/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/neon/vfp", 0xbeab1178) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/neon/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/neon", 0xbeab1178)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/vfp", 0xbeab1178)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls", 0xbeab1178)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/v7l/neon/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbeab1178) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/v7l/neon/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l/neon", 0xbeab1178)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/v7l/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l/vfp", 0xbeab1178)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/v7l/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l", 0xbeab1178)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/neon/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/neon/vfp", 0xbeab1178)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/neon/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/neon", 0xbeab1178)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/vfp", 0xbeab1178)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\211\260\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=931444, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1001036, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6e40000
mprotect(0xb6f20000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6f2f000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xdf000) = 0xb6f2f000
mmap2(0xb6f33000, 5708, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f33000
close(3)                                = 0
set_tls(0xb6f973f0)                     = 0
mprotect(0xb6f2f000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6f56000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6f6e000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x4d4000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0xb6f9a000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xb6f98000, 6146)                = 0
set_tid_address(0xb6f96f18)             = 656
set_robust_list(0xb6f96f20, 12)         = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0xb6f3a20d, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0xb6e6a291}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0xb6f3a291, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0xb6e6a291}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
ugetrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
clock_gettime64(CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE, {tv_sec=1520599284, tv_nsec=439968873}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x4dd000
brk(0x4fe000)                           = 0x4fe000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0xfd, 0), ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B115200 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
write(1, "Main sleep at 24 seconds\n", 25Main sleep at 24 seconds
) = 25
clock_nanosleep_time64(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=3, tv_nsec=3761122102560686080},










0xbeab1bd0) = 0
clock_gettime64(CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE, {tv_sec=1520599287, tv_nsec=449968632}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(1, "Main wakeup at 27 seconds\n", 26Main wakeup at 27 seconds
) = 26
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Note, I had to once again repeatedly press enter to get the output after the call to sleep() to print.

Comment: We need enough code to replicate the issue. I can think of a lot of things it could be, but without seeing all the other code needed to cause the issue, there's no way to say. Remove some code, see if you can still replicate the issue. If not, put it back and try removing other code. Keep going until you have all the code needed to replicate the issue and no code you can't remove. Then update your question.

Comment: Just a guess ... See `man 3 sleep`. On linux, `sleep` calls `nanosleep`, so it's fine. But, on some systems, `sleep` is implemented using `alarm` (`SIGALRM`). So, if somebody else is setting such an alarm (or via `setitimer`), you may want to use `nanosleep` to be _sure_ as it is _guaranteed_ to work correctly with `SIGALRM`

Comment: As a test, you could use `time/clock_gettime` to get starting time. Then, loop until it reaches four seconds (in lieu of doing `sleep`) to see if that works. Either way, it will tell you something.

Comment: @alexv9, `sleep(s);` has a return value. What is it?

Comment: Does your main thread call `join()` on the sleeping/printf'ing thread before returning?  If not, it might be that your program is sometimes exiting before the child thread has a chance to reach the second call to `printf()`.  When the process exits, any threads still present will be killed, even if they are still e.g. in the middle of a `sleep()` call.

Comment: The codebase is large, it's hard to get you an isolated example. I disabled every other thread from getting started except for the thread in question and the issue is still present. Also, the issue only occurs on zedbpoard running petalinux, not on my host machine. 

I checked the return value of sleep() and nanosleep(), both return 0. The thread is indeed sleeping for four seconds, I route some of my debug statements to a log file (and also printf() them). I can see the statements in my log file and they are 4 seconds apart, but no output to stdout.

Comment: Main thread is calling join(), so it is not exiting prematurely

Comment: The mystery continues...

I reduced the nanosleep() time to 2 seconds and now no issue, printf() works as expected. If i change it to 3 seconds then the issue occurs.

Comment: _it is not printing to stdout when I run it without file redirect._ petalinux is running inside an FPGA, so not totally like a PC impl. In that environment, `stdout` may be directed, by default, to (e.g.) `/dev/null`. Does `>/dev/stdout` or `>/dev/tty` help? Does `dmesg` or `/var/log/messages` (or whatever `systemd` [monstrous] equiv) show anything? Your latest message says it's only about the timeout (e.g. 2 secs okay, but more produces bad results), so none of my suggested ideas may be valid, but, if it were me I'd try those to see. They may give a clue.

Comment: Another [random] thought ... When I was dealing with petalinux [years ago], I sometimes had issues with the UART [to USB/FTDI] cable. Are RTS/CTS wired correctly and/or does the comm program on the PC (e.g. `putty` or `minicom`) have the correct port options to assert and/or ignore RTS/CTS?

Comment: You should run the program under strace (and/or ltrace) to see what is going on in terms of low level services.

Comment: Looking at the strace output, the program is launched from /usr/bin. Is it the one you are expecting or do you run one program resulting from your PATH instead of the one located in your local directory ? We can also see that the program dynamically links with both rt and pthread.  How do you build this program? Because as it is monothreaded, it should not need the latter libs. Moreover you have a weird call to ugetrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}): this is normally in the initialization of the pthread lib to determine the default stack size of the threads.

Comment: You can also add `-tt -f` to your `strace` options to show *when* each system call is made *and* which process/thread makes the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the serial console of the zedboard. I noticed that the same issue was occurring at startup, a certain system call at startup was blocking for a bit to set something up and that was causing subsequent startup messages to not be shown. The console prompt wouldn't show up either until I hit enter, the exact same issue I was seeing with running the above code.

So it is something with the serial console that is going bad. Over ssh, the issue is not present. I am not sure if it is on my end (I am using screen) or on the zedboard end (it is using getty).

Anyway, not the end of the world, thank you all for your help.